# How am I supposed to store a value from my database as a variable in php using PHP and SQL?

Tags: php, arrays, phpmyadmin

I would like to see where my code is incorrect. I want to store values from my database as a php array. Then I'd like to store the individual parts of the array as separate variables. Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT column FROM table");
    if (!$result) {
        echo 'Could not run query';
        exit;
    }
    $comments = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    $comment0 = $comments[0];
    $comment1 = $comments[1];
    $comment2 = $comments[2];
    $comment3 = $comments[3];
    $comment4 = $comments[4];
    $comment5 = $comments[5];
    $comment6 = $comments[6];
    $comment7 = $comments[7];
    $comment8 = $comments[8];
    $comment9 = $comments[9];
?>
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: Are you trying to loop through the results? Or are you trying to specify each result as a variable you can use somewhere else later?

Answer (score 1):

This will run your mysql query and add each comment to an array of comments, then print the array.

```
   <?php
        $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT column FROM table");
        if (!$result) {
            echo 'Could not run query';
            exit;
        }
        $comments = array();
        while($comment = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
            $comments[] = $comment;
        }
        print_r($comments);

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you are in console or through web server.

```
<?php
    $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT column FROM table");
    if (!$result) {
        echo 'Could not run query';
        exit;
    }
    $comments = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

foreach($comments as $comment){
    echo print_r($comment,1).'--------------\r\n<br>\r\n';
}
?>
```

this is called a loop. loop is your friend.